# Remove duplicated rows from two datatables with different numbers of rows

Tags: uipath

I have two datatables, in one of them `old_DataTable` I have 3 results. In the other one called `Output` I have 4 results. I have been implementing solutions suggested in forums:

1. Read the two `Datatables`
2. drCommonRows = (From d1 In old_DataTable.AsEnumerable
   Join d2 In Output.AsEnumerable
   On d1("StartDate").toString.Trim Equals d2("StartDate").toString.Trim
   Select d1).ToList
3. `drFilteredRows=old_DataTable.AsEnumerable.Except(drCommonRows, DataRowComparer.Default).toList`
4. If drFilteredRows.Count >0 than dtFiltered drFilteredRows.CopyToDataTable
   Else dtFiltered old_DataTable.Clone

When testing it gives a good result of `drCommonRows` but not of `drFilteredRows` and in the IF condition it always goes in Else.

I even changed the : `drFilteredRows=**old_DataTable**.AsEnumerable.Except(drCommonRows, DataRowComparer.Default).toList`

into

`drFilteredRows=**Output**.AsEnumerable.Except(drCommonRows, DataRowComparer.Default).toList` but in that case it gives as result all the datatable saved in `Output` so gives 4 results and is not working.

```
> The result that I am expecting is 1 row that is the one which is
> different and is in the Output Datatable.
```

Comment: Please next time improve the formatting of your text, as it helps many here to be able to give proper help.